# How To Use Variable Value Outside Block?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios8, objective-c-blocks

I have the following code that is checking the connectivity of my app.  I want to display the connectivity status in a UILabel that is on a custom UIView that slides in when the connectivity status changes.

[EDIT]

```
__block NSString * strConnectivityStatus = @"";

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

[END EDIT]

```
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));

    strConnectivityStatus = AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status);

    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            viewConnectivityStatus.hidden = false;
            lblConnectivityStatus.text = AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status);
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            viewConnectivityStatus.hidden = false;
            lblConnectivityStatus.text = AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status);
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            viewConnectivityStatus.hidden = false;
            lblConnectivityStatus.text = AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status);
        default:
            viewConnectivityStatus.hidden = false;
            lblConnectivityStatus.text = AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status);
            break;
    }

}];
```

and then I call my custom UIView which slides into position:

```
OLSlidingMessageVC *msgConnectivityVC = [[OLSlidingMessageVC alloc] initWithTitleAndPosition:@"STATUS" message:strConnectivityStatus msgHeight:&viewHeight msgWidth:&viewWidth msgXPos:&viewXPos msgYPos:&viewYPos];
```

but the strConnectivityStatus is always blank as I cannot access its value outside of the block.

How can I get the status to appear on the UILabel on my UIView?

Comment: Use __block modifier for strConnectivityStatus.

Comment: @gagarwal I have edited the post because I already had that __block modifier in the definition of the variable.  I want to use the value elsewhere in my code outside of the block where its value is set.

Comment: @gagarwal: Using `__block` is useless because the problem is the block is called asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Then block is not called synchronously, so `strConnectivityStatus` won't be set anywhere outside the block.

Just make `strConnectivityStatus` a local variable inside the block and perform any action you need inside the block.

Comment: I want to use the value set inside the block elsewhere outside the block.

Comment: @motionpotion: I know. But that's not possible for the simple reason that *"outside the block" happens before the block is run*.